# Javaw.exe - Approximately 60 Instances Running Simultaneously

Tags: eclipse, memory, javaw

Upon checking Task Manager (Windows 7), I have approximately 60 instances of `javaw.exe` running, ranging from approx. 1,000K - 450,000K.

I am currently working on a large project, developing some software using Eclipse Helios.

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of possible reasons for this, but in my experience the most likely is that instances of your app that you are starting to test or debug are staying around after you think they are gone.

Comment: How is this an accepted solution to the problem? Mick, can you elaborate on how you solved the issue?

Comment: @aglassman - Yes, I can elaborate on how I solved the issue and I will do so as follows. To begin, it is clearly obvious - I selected this as the solution because the instances of my app were, as antlersoft puts it, "staying around" after I thought they are gone.  Thus, I added a line to terminate the instance of the app after each run.  It really is that simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly stop the previous instance, and click the "Run As" (Green Arrow) button again, the previous instance will just keep running in the background.  In the console tab, there is a drop down which will show all running instances.  You need to click the red box on each of these to kill the process.

Comment: I always stop the current process before beginning another and this has never happened before.  I have been using Eclipse for a long time and am very familiar with the way it works.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I know I've run into a similar issue, I just have to remember what it was now!  Are you kicking off any Threads in your application?  Those may be keeping the main process alive.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in Eclipse. When you stop the console - clicking the big red button - the javaw.exe process carries on running.

You solve it by opening task manager, identifying the javaw.exe process that isn't for Eclipse (go to show columns and show "command line") and then right click: end task